# Android Studio and Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, android, ssl, android-studio, bouncycastle

I'm trying to make an android app that should connect to a HTTPS server using a specific certificate.

I'm using Android Studio 1.4 on a Mac running OSX El Capitan

I have successfully extracted the certificate key to a cert.pem file and made it into a keystore using the following command:

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "cert.pem" -alias an_alias -keystore "server.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "bcprov-jdk16-146.jar" -storetype BKS
```

However, when it comes time to run the code, it gives me the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

I've found some answers regarding this error, but they're pretty old and the proposed solution, namely delete bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar from Library/Java/Extensions, but I did so and it didn't solve my issue.

Also in another answer I've found the suggestion of adding this to build.gradle:

```
Class klass = org.bouncycastle.asn1.bc.BCObjectIdentifiers.class;
URL location = klass.getResource('/'+klass.getName().replace('.', '/')+".class");
println location.toURI().toString();
```

And upon building gives me this, but I'm still at a loss as to what is happening:

```
jar:file:/Users/Me/Library/Java/Extensions/bcprov-jdk15on-146.jar!/org/bouncycastle/asn1/bc/BCObjectIdentifiers.class
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Don't use bouncycastle on Android, use spongycastle.

Comment: Will try, are there any big differences between both libraries that I should be wary of?